# How can I get quickkey after upload file into mediafire specific folder?

Tags: php, jquery, mediafire

**After upload file i am getting this response.**

```
Array
(
    [result] => 0
    [status] => 6
    [description] => Verifying File
    [fileerror] => 
    [quickkey] => 
    [hash] => 
    [filename] => 
    [size] => 
    [created] => 
    [revision] => 
    [resumable_upload] => 
    [result_message] => Success
    [fileerror_message] => 
)
```

I need to upload file into mediafire storage into specific directory. After Upload task done I need to get quickkey and other details about file.